# Prolog string manipulation

Tags: prolog

I have a string like `'pen,pencil,eraser'`. How can I make this predicate.

```
things(pen,pencil,eraser).
```

Do you have any idea? ( I use prolog)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but what is the context? Which language? Or just logic?

Comment: @Heandel: Yes @Ben retagged it.... I hope it's right ;)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. I use prolog.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a small example of specialized Prolog code for your problem which should work on most implementations (not only SWI-Prolog, but GNU Prolog, SICStus, etc.):

```
make_term(Functor, StringArgs, Term) :-
    split_atom(StringArgs, ',', Args),
    Term =.. [Functor|Args].        

split_atom(A, E, L) :-
    atom_chars(A, C),
    split_atom2(C, E, L).

split_atom2([], _, []).
split_atom2(C, E, [A|L]) :-
    append(C0, [E|C1], C), !,
    atom_chars(A, C0),
    split_atom2(C1, E, L).
split_atom2(C, _, [A]) :-
    atom_chars(A, C).
```

Testing it out:

```
?- make_term(things, 'pen,pencil,eraser', T).
T = things(pen, pencil, eraser).
```

Answer (score 2):

if you use swi-prolog, you can create this first: 'things(pen,pencil,eraser)' and then use [term_to_atom/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=term_to_atom/2)

so something like:

```
get_term(Term):-
    atom_concat('things(','pen,pencil,eraser',Temp),
    atom_concat(Temp,')',A),
    term_to_atom(Term, A).
```